# I'm not sure if pygame.mixer.init works

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspbian

I execute following code

```
import pygame
import pygame.mixer

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()
print pygame.mixer.get_init()
```

and it prints

```
(22050, -16, 2)
```

So I'm not sure if it works. I expect it would show `(44100,-16,1)`. Is it correct or am I missing something?

I'm using python-pygame 1.9.1 and python 2.7.9 on my raspi with raspbian jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. `pygame.init()` should be called after `pygame.mixer.pre_init()`

So

```
import pygame
import pygame.mixer

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 2048)
pygame.init()
print pygame.mixer.get_init()
```

works as expected.